# Rails Activerecord query with an array of objects returns multiple duplicates of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a series of checkboxes a user can use to find objects by the checked attributes. I want them to be able to select a number of attributes and then be shown a list of objects that contain *all* of those checked attributes.

My code is partially working, except that if I check one attribute and I'm given a list and then I check another attribute, that was already displayed from the previous check, then I'm given another copy. Here is an image of what is happening. Notice that objects are being repeated.

[image]

Here is the code that goes with it:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="dropdown package-dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Attributes</button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="attr1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>attr1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="attr2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>attr2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="attr3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>attr3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="attr4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>attr4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="attr5" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>attr5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- removed irrelevant code for brevity -->

  <tbody id="hits">
    <% @objects.each do |obj| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to obj.title, obj_path(obj) %></td>
          <td class="package-column">
          <% if obj.packages.any? %>
            <div>
            <% obj.packages.each do |p| %>
              <span><%= image_tag "needs-#{p.kind}", :alt => "#{p.kind}", :class => "foobar" %></span>
            <% end %>
            </div>
          <% else %>
            <div class="package-column"><span>...</span></div>
        <% end %>
        </td>
        <td><%= obj.capacity %></td>
        <td><%= obj.started_at.strftime('%A, %B %e, %Y at %l:%M %p') if obj.started_at? %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    <tr><td colspan="4" align="center"><%= link_to "Load More", objects_path, class: "load-more" %></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

var options = [];
$('.dropdown-menu li a').on( 'click', function(event) {
 var $target = $( event.currentTarget ),
     val = $target.attr( 'data-value' ),
     $inp = $target.find( 'input' ),
     idx;

 if ( ( idx = options.indexOf( val ) ) > -1 ) {
    options.splice( idx, 1 );
    setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', false ) }, 0);
 } else {
    options.push( val );
    setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', true ) }, 0);
 }

 $( event.target ).blur();

  console.log( options );
  $.ajax({
    url:  $(this).attr('href'),
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      packages: options
    },
    dataType: "script"
  })
  return false;
});
```

My controller where the active record query is.

```
def index
  if params[:packages]
    packages = params[:packages] # ["attr1", "attr3" etc..]
    @objects = Object.joins(:packages).where("packages.kind IN (?)", packages)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

I am sure it's an Activerecord issue and not a display issue because if I inspect `@objects` I'm shown multiple copies of records like so:

```
[8] pry(#<ObjectsController>)> @objects
=> [#<Object:0x007f991cb1d6b0
  id: 2,
  uuid: "1adede0e-8585-41a5-8c74-8de8eec6a141",
  name: "andy-title1",
  title: "Andy - Title1",
  started_at: Mon, 27 Mar 2017 13:00:24 PDT -07:00,
  ended_at: Mon, 27 Mar 2017 18:00:24 PDT -07:00
 #<Object:0x007f991cb1d548
  id: 2,
  uuid: "1adede0e-8585-41a5-8c74-8de8eec6a141",
  name: "andy-title1",
  title: "Andy - Title1",
  started_at: Mon, 27 Mar 2017 13:00:24 PDT -07:00,
  ended_at: Mon, 27 Mar 2017 18:00:24 PDT -07:00
```

Comment: Note sure if this will fix it, but the problem may be related to the fact that your model is called `Object`. I strongly suggest that you rename it to something more descriptive of the data it holds. `Object` is the name of one of the most basic classes in ruby and if you use it as a model you might have some subtle namespace collisions and could see extremely weird behavior. I don't _think_ this is related to your current problem, but it may be and you should change it nonetheless.

Comment: That was done to obscure the data I'm working on. It's not really called `Object`

Comment: Well, nevermind then. I was actually wondering how you managed to get Object to inherit ActiveRecord::Base in the first place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `.distinct` to the end of my query solved my issues and will omit duplicate records.

My now working query is:

`@objects = Object.joins(:packages).where("packages.kind IN (?)", packages).distinct`

Comment: I think it's a quirk of SQL joins that allows duplicates to be returned in some cases. Your solution using distinct seems correct here.